# On scroll take to specific location with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not too sure how to describe this with words; but what I am planning to do is something like what this website has achieved: http://sapia.com.pe/

When you scroll down, it takes you to a specific point of the page, as well as when you scroll up. How could I do this using Jquery? Would any plugins be needed?

Comment: The site you linked is using: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **SNIPPET** below it will give you basic idea how it can be achieved

or you can use plugins like [fullpage](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

```js
var arr = ['_a','_b','_c'];
var i=0;
var doing=false;
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
            if(i==-1) i=2;
            if(!doing){
             $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $("#"+arr[i--]).offset().top
              }, 600,function(){doing=false;});
             doing=true;
           }
        }
        else{
             if(i==3) i=0;
            if(!doing){
             $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $("#"+arr[i++]).offset().top
              }, 600,function(){doing=false;});
             doing=true;
           }
        }
 });
```

```css
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.section,html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.a{ background-color:red; }
.b{ background-color:yellow; }
.c{ background-color:blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="_a" class="section a"></div>
<div id="_b" class="section b"></div>
<div id="_c" class="section c"></div>
```