# Can someone explain to me how setting a set amount of pixels the scroll function can scroll down/up to using jquery works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, transform

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
// scroll 100vh down on first scroll

// scroll another 100vh down on second scroll
})
```

I've seen a plugin that does just this but I want to be able to understand how the logic works. Can someone please explain it to me or at least point me to a site where it can be explained further?

Comment: It tells you here what https://api.jquery.com/scroll/ `scroll()` is

Comment: It turns any scroll into a full page scroll like at http://www.squaredot.eu

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ //Function called when window is scrolled.

})
```

[JQuery Scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set
>   to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less
>   than the height or width of its contents).

When the width/height of a div is more than the available width/height of the device browser will provide you a scroll bar to scroll down and see overflowed elements.

Jquery scroll allows you to listen to a event when a user scrolls inside the selector provided.

It will call your handler (function) that you passed as a parameter to the scroll function of jquery.

Further, you don't need to scroll an container manually. The browser will automatically scroll the contents of the overflowed container but you may want to increase the step of scroll by the scrollbar.

How do you increase the step?

Normally, when you scroll the `scrollTop` property of your scrollable container changes with a fixed step (1-10px).

This `scrollTop` property decides how much of content is overflowed from the top of the srollable container and shows more pixels from the bottom of the container its like a viewport.

So, you can add more number of pixel to `scrollTop` and scroll more than default.

Checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288557/on-scroll-take-to-specific-location-with-jquery-or-javascript/44289104#44289104) of mine

Comment: How does one increase the step of scroll exactly? because I need to know how one flick of the mousewheel down can translate to moving the page exactly 100vh down i.e. fullPage.js

Comment: checkout this answer of mine
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288557/on-scroll-take-to-specific-location-with-jquery-or-javascript/44289104#44289104

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what's going on, i'm pretty new, could you explain it more in details if it's not too much to ask? also the animation seems to be glitchy